# How to make 3D matplotlib artists (line, text, path) always visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I work on a project, where I need to show cuboids (Poly3DCollection) with other artists(texts, paths) **always visible**. No matter if the artists are inside, outside or behind the cuboids. I know about matplotlib 3D limits and I don’t need realistic model, but for me it is better to make artists always visible than having "randomly" visible. I know I could change opacity of the cuboids, but this leads to changes in artists colours while rotating the plot. I found a workaround to make always visible line, but I would like to achieve the same effect with paths(need curves) and texts. I have prepared short examples with cube taken from another SO question. Only last few lines are important for this question. The main reason why I use matplotlib is that I have tkinter GUI.

**Example 1:**
sometimes is visible whole green line, sometimes just part of it

**Example 2:**
solution to example one is to include edges of the cube a and set linewidth to 0. This leads to always visible blue line which is the desired behaviour for my project

**Example 3 and 4:**
green text and black pathpatch are randomly visible while rotating.

**QUESTION:**
Is there better workaround to make line always visible? Is there any solution to make text or path always visible?

Thank you for your time and help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection, pathpatch_2d_to_3d

# YOU CAN SKIP THIS (It is taken from another SO question)
cube_definition = [(0, 0, 0), (0, 3, 0), (3, 0, 0), (0, 0, 3)]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

cube_definition_array = [
    np.array(list(item))
    for item in cube_definition
]

points = []
points += cube_definition_array
vectors = [
    cube_definition_array[1] - cube_definition_array[0],
    cube_definition_array[2] - cube_definition_array[0],
    cube_definition_array[3] - cube_definition_array[0]
]

points += [cube_definition_array[0] + vectors[0] + vectors[1]]
points += [cube_definition_array[0] + vectors[0] + vectors[2]]
points += [cube_definition_array[0] + vectors[1] + vectors[2]]
points += [cube_definition_array[0] + vectors[0] + vectors[1] + vectors[2]]

points = np.array(points)

edges = [
    [points[0], points[3], points[5], points[1]],
    [points[1], points[5], points[7], points[4]],
    [points[7], points[6], points[2], points[4]],
    [points[2], points[6], points[3], points[0]],
    [points[1], points[4], points[2], points[0]],
    [points[3], points[6], points[7], points[5]]
]

faces = Poly3DCollection(edges, linewidths=1, edgecolors='none', facecolors='red')
ax.add_collection3d(faces)

# IMPORTANT STARTS HERE


# Example 1:
inner_line = [[[-1, -1, -1], [2.5, 2, 2.5]]]
ax.add_collection3d(Line3DCollection(inner_line, linewidths=1, edgecolors='g'))

# Example 2:
inner_line = [[[-1, -1, -1], [2, 2, 2]]]
ax.add_collection3d(Line3DCollection(edges + inner_line, linewidths=[0] * len(edges) + [1], edgecolors='b'))

# Example 3:
ax.text(1, 1, 1, "test text", color='g')

# Exampe 4:
path = Path([[-1.5, -1.5, ], [2.5, 2.5]], [Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO])
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, color='k', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)
pathpatch_2d_to_3d(patch, z=0, zdir='z')

# show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Giving those "always on top" artists a very high `zorder` parameter should be sufficient.

Comment: Zorder seems to have effect only on text. PathPatch and Line3DCollection ignore it. I thought (or read somewhere) that zorder is only for 2D plots. But this helps me anyway. Thank you. Now I have to find solution for path.

Comment: I spent some time with google and found out that in matplotlib 3.5.0 will be added new option to force zordering. I took one line from this code and modified original source file and now patchpath are finaly always on top.
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14508/files/61451ee7419fe35f4105ec848191e2b4bf22680c#